# Inserting elements using javascript into html

Tags: javascript

I wanna ask that is there any way to insert html content using javascript in such a way like i have a table and inside there is a tbody and inside that i am inserting element using javascript like i am inserting tr and inside that tr i am inserting 5 td and i want that 5 td to have different content and if you try to put all the above stuff in code it will look something like this

```
for(let i = 1; i< 38; i++){
        
        let swd = {
            active: data.statewise[i].active,
            confirmed: data.statewise[i].confirmed,
            deaths: data.statewise[i].deaths,
            recovered: data.statewise[i].recovered
        }

        let swdb = document.getElementById('swdb');

        let swtr = document.createElement('tr');

        swdb.appendChild(swtr);

        for(let j = 1; j<6; j++){
            let swtd = document.createElement('td');
            swtr.appendChild(swtd);
        }
    }
```

and challenge for me is to insert different content in td inside same tr. And after that final html code should look like this :-

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>Custom content 1</td>
                        <td id="active"> Custom content 2</td>
                        <td id="conf">Custom content 3</td>
                        <td id="deaths">Custom content 4</td>
                        <td id="recov">Custom content 5</td>
                    </tr>
```

and after that i will generate more tr like this.

Hope you understand my problem and help me!

Comment: You asked a question and answered it with pseudo code. Do you have a specific programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the same example as @b3hr4d but u shouldn't use `.innerHTML` on plain text, choose between `.textContent` and `.innerText`. Good luck =)

```js
const contentList = [
  { id: "", text: 'Custom content 1' },
  { id: 'active', text: 'Custom content 2' },
];

const tr = document.createElement('tr');
contentList.forEach(({ id, text }) => {
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  if (id) td.setAttribute('id', id);
  td.textContent = text;
  tr.appendChild(td);
});

const root = document.querySelector('#root');
root.appendChild(tr);
```

result

```html
<div id="root">
  <tr>
    <td>Custom content 1</td>
    <td id="active">Custom content 2</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I undrestood you just need [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) for adding content inside td:

you can make an array of object like this:

```
const customContent = [
    {id:"",content:"Custom content 1"},
    {id:"active",content:data.statewise[i].active},
    {id:"confirmed",content:data.statewise[i].confirmed},
    {id:"deaths",content:data.statewise[i].deaths},
    {id:"recov",content:data.statewise[i].recovered},
]
```

And use them like this:

```
customContent.forEach(item => {
  let swtd = document.createElement('td');
  swtd.id = item.id;
  swtd.innerText = item.content;
  swtr.appendChild(swtd);
});
```